# Pyspark: OOM Unable to create a new thread

Tags: multithreading, apache-spark, pyspark

I'm running a Spark job from the pyspark shell and get the

```
Exception in thread "stdout writer for python2.7" java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: unable to create new native thread
    at java.lang.Thread.start0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Thread.start(Thread.java:714)
    at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRDD.compute(PythonRDD.scala:92)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:277)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:244)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.UnionRDD.compute(UnionRDD.scala:87)
...
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:244)
    at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRDD$WriterThread$$anonfun$run$3.apply(PythonRDD.scala:248)
    at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.logUncaughtExceptions(Utils.scala:1772)
    at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRDD$WriterThread.run(PythonRDD.scala:208)
```

The job is picking a dataframe from Parquet files, transforms to RDD, performs transformation and stores result to other Parquet files.

The same issue happens when running in 1 node standalone mode as well as running on a small 2 nodes YARN cluster.
The same issue persists when I increase the default pyspark shell parameters:

```
pyspark --driver-memory 8G --executor-memory 8G
```

Before the exception is thrown (and the processing stops) there are a couple of warnings in the console:

```
15/09/13 00:12:17 WARN TaskSetManager: Stage 186 contains a task of very large size (4722 KB). The maximum recommended task size is 100 KB.
15/09/13 00:12:19 ERROR ShuffleBlockFetcherIterator: Error occurred while fetching local blocks
java.lang.InterruptedException
    at java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.acquireInterruptibly(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:1220)
    at java.util.concurrent.locks.ReentrantLock.lockInterruptibly(ReentrantLock.java:335)
    at java.util.concurrent.LinkedBlockingQueue.put(LinkedBlockingQueue.java:339)
    at org.apache.spark.storage.ShuffleBlockFetcherIterator.fetchLocalBlocks(ShuffleBlockFetcherIterator.scala:239)
    at org.apache.spark.storage.ShuffleBlockFetcherIterator.initialize(ShuffleBlockFetcherIterator.scala:269)
    at org.apache.spark.storage.ShuffleBlockFetcherIterator.<init>(ShuffleBlockFetcherIterator.scala:115)
    at org.apache.spark.shuffle.hash.BlockStoreShuffleFetcher$.fetch(BlockStoreShuffleFetcher.scala:76)
    at org.apache.spark.shuffle.hash.HashShuffleReader.read(HashShuffleReader.scala:40)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.ShuffledRDD.compute(ShuffledRDD.scala:90)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:277)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:244)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:35)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:277)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:244)
    at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRDD$WriterThread$$anonfun$run$3.apply(PythonRDD.scala:248)
    at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.logUncaughtExceptions(Utils.scala:1772)
    at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRDD$WriterThread.run(PythonRDD.scala:208)
```

And

```
15/09/13 00:12:21 WARN TaskSetManager: Stage 369 contains a task of very large size (4722 KB). The maximum recommended task size is 100 KB.
15/09/13 00:12:21 ERROR ShuffleBlockFetcherIterator: Error occurred while fetching local blocks
java.lang.InterruptedException
at java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.acquireInterruptibly(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:1220)
at java.util.concurrent.locks.ReentrantLock.lockInterruptibly(ReentrantLock.java:335)
at java.util.concurrent.LinkedBlockingQueue.put(LinkedBlockingQueue.java:339)
at org.apache.spark.storage.ShuffleBlockFetcherIterator.fetchLocalBlocks(ShuffleBlockFetcherIterator.scala:239)
at org.apache.spark.storage.ShuffleBlockFetcherIterator.initialize(ShuffleBlockFetcherIterator.scala:269)
at org.apache.spark.storage.ShuffleBlockFetcherIterator.<init>(ShuffleBlockFetcherIterator.scala:115)
at org.apache.spark.shuffle.hash.BlockStoreShuffleFetcher$.fetch(BlockStoreShuffleFetcher.scala:76)
at org.apache.spark.shuffle.hash.HashShuffleReader.read(HashShuffleReader.scala:40)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.ShuffledRDD.compute(ShuffledRDD.scala:90)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:277)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:244)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:35)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:277)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:244)
at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRDD$WriterThread$$anonfun$run$3.apply(PythonRDD.scala:248)
at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.logUncaughtExceptions(Utils.scala:1772)
at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRDD$WriterThread.run(PythonRDD.scala:208)
```

Some answers to similar questions mention that such situation happen because the Spark's memory is not properly tuned.
How should the Spark memory be tuned? Which settings are affecting this behaviour?

The first stack trace is huge and consists of the same several methods being recursively called. If I also monitor the Spark JVM at the time of the crash there's a huge spike of the currently running threads that "breaks through the roof".
All that looks like some kind of poor internal Java `ThreadPoolExector` based implementation that doesn't limit the number of threads in case if tasks start getting processed slower than the new are coming.

Which configuration knobs can help me preventing that sudden thread creation spike?